# Square roots of Jordan blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

It is known that for the Jordan block
$$ J_p = \left(\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda & 1& \ldots & 0\\
0  &  \lambda& & 0\\
0 & 0  &  \ddots & 1 \\
0 &0 &\ldots &  \lambda \\
\end{array}}^{p}\right)$$
the following formulas are valid:
$$
e^{J_p}= e^{\lambda} \sum_{r=0}^{p-1} \frac1{r!} I_r^{(p)};
\qquad
{\mathrm{Ln}} {J_p}= I\; {\mathrm{Ln}} \lambda+ \sum_{r=1}^{p-1} \frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r \lambda^r} I_r^{(p)},
$$
where
$$
I_1^{(p)} = \left(\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1& \ldots & 0\\
0  &  0& & 0\\
0 & 0  &  \ddots & 1 \\
0 &0 &\ldots &  0 \\
\end{array}}^{p}\right),\quad
I_2^{(p)} = \left(\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0& 1& 0& \ldots & 0\\
0  &  0& 0& 1&\ldots & 0\\
0  &  0& 0& 0&  \ddots & 1 \\
0  &  0& 0& 0&\ldots &  0 \\
0  &  0& 0& 0&\ldots &  0 \\
\end{array}}^{p}\right) \mbox{etc.}
$$
My question is whether there is a similar formula for the square root.
After some numerical experiments, I think yes. In particular,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)^2=
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right),
\quad
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & \frac{1}{4} & - \frac{1}{64}\\ 0 & 2 & \frac{1}{4}\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array}\right)^2
=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 4 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 4 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{array}\right),
\quad
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & \frac{1}{6} & - \frac{1}{216}\\ 0 & 3 & \frac{1}{6}\\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{array}\right)^2=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 9 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 9 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 9 \end{array}\right)
$$
assumes the existence of a similar formula. Maybe someone knows it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]
We have $J_p = \lambda I + I_1^{(p)}$.
The binomial series $$ \sqrt{\lambda + x} = \sqrt{\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose k} \left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^k $$
applies.  Since $(I_1^{(p)})^k = 0$ for $k > p$, it becomes a finite series
$$ \sqrt{J_p} = \sum_{k=0}^p {1/2 \choose k} \lambda^{1/2-k} I_k^{(p)} $$
Here you can also write
$$ {1/2 \choose k} = (-1)^{k+1} 2^{1-2k} \frac{(2k-2)! }{k! (k-1)!}  \ \text{for}\ k \ge 1 $$

Comment: @AVK Oops, thanks for catching that.  I edited, now it should be OK.  For $p = 2$ it's $$\pmatrix{\sqrt{\lambda} & 1/(2 \sqrt{\lambda})\cr 0 & \sqrt{\lambda}}^2 = \pmatrix{\lambda & 1\cr 0 & \lambda} $$